# How to css Views Tree module theme

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am using the module [Views Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree). Apparently, it gets the hierarchical listing of taxonomy terms, and outputs a tree with indentation levels (two levels).

However, I am not able to style or css it, because the overriden tpl.php ( views-tree.tpl.php ) does not exist, and when I copy views-view-row.tpl.php in the theme folder, renaming the file to views-tree.tpl.php I almost get it, except that the rendering is: first the parent taxonomy terms, and next the children terms. Exactly as without the module.

So I am unable to use none of the available .tpl.php for **Views**, and cannot change the style, only with css, which is not adequate (there are ul tags which I want to have different classes, for example).

So, sadly, I must use template.php and views_get_view_result to recover the View and css it, which is exactly as not having the module installed at all! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I discovered that the module uses the core listing resources, so the theming can be achieved via template.php and function **NAMEOFTEMPLATE_item_list**($variables). The only caveat is that, as the call to this function is recursive, you will need some tricks to know in which level you are. Those tricks could depend on the listing itself; another solution would be to modify the module itself to send the level.

Honestly, I think this in an example of a module whose existence is questionable. A direct treatment of the View_results is much faster and easier to theme.